# error can not Creating a Docker Container with django project

Tags: python, django, docker

i trying to creating container for django project so but an error show with SECRET KEY in `settings.py` file

when i run `docker command`

```
docker run --publish 8000:8000 python-django
```

error with SECRET_KEY show that i am unable to build docker container

[image]

settings.py file

```
    ...


# UPDATE secret key
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

....
```

Answer (score 0):

Add environment variable in your command as

`docker run -e SECRET_KEY='SECRET_KEY_VALUE' --publish 8000:8000 python-django`

Comment: still not working another error appears"docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "-e": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown."

Comment: I have updated the command. The environment variable must be set before not after the image name.